# PHP getting headers sent with curl

Tags: php, curl

i have 2 files client.php and server.php. I want to send headers from client to server with curl, and then read this headers in server, but unfortunately I can't get the headers in server file. I tried to do this by using `getallheaders()` but nothing was displayed. Then I tried `get_headers()` which says null, when i used `var_dump` on it.

My client code:
`
   $result = sendRequest();
    echo "res: ".$result;

```
function sendRequest()
{ 
    $method = 'test';
    $params = array();
    $params["method"] = $method; 
    $post = http_build_query($params, "", "&"); 
    $headers = array(
        "API-Key: test",
        "API-Key2: test2",
        "API-Key3: test3",
        "API-Key4: test4",
    ); 


    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/server.php"); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $ret = curl_exec($curl); 

    return $ret; 
}
```

and the server.php:

```
get();

function get()
{
    $head = get_headers();
    var_dump($head);
}
```

Comment: What php version are you using?

Comment: Server: Apache/2 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20

Comment: I suggest the errors are disabled on your server. Can you insert to your code to provide more information: 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function getallheaders()

i expected that one, but it doesn't change nothing, because I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Can you try var_dump($_SERVER) to see your headers?

Comment: after var_dump($_SERVER) i got long array, and i.a. my 4 headers:
`  ["HTTP_API_KEY"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["HTTP_API_KEY2"]=>
  string(5) "test2"
  ["HTTP_API_KEY3"]=>
  string(5) "test3"
  ["HTTP_API_KEY4"]=>
  string(5) "test4"`
but is it only way to get this?

Comment: Function headers_list() might help, but there is bug in php, function returns empty array. However, u can try.

Comment: Using headers_list() i got only X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.20, my headers sent by curl are not displayed...

Comment: Finally, only $_SERVER works. It's not bad way get headers from $_SERVER

Comment: Ok, it's not bad. This should be enough for me :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetches all HTTP request headers from the current request with

```
apache_request_headers();
```

look at [php.net apache-request-headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php)

if apache_request_headers() is not available, loop trough the superglobal `$_SERVER` and get info you need, the request headers starting with `HTTP_`, like

```
$headers = array();

foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/^HTTP_.+/', $key)) {
        // sanitize keys removing HTTP_
        $headers[str_replace('HTTP_','',$key)] = $value;
    }
}
```

to use

```
echo $headers['API-Key'];
```

Comment: Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()

Comment: @Rocket In PHP 5.4.0 this function became available under FastCGI. Previously, it was supported only when PHP was installed as an Apache module.

Comment: Server API: CGI/FastCGI
PHP Version 5.3.20
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2

Comment: @Rocket then [install php as an apache module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php) or get your request headers directly from $_SERVER

Comment: @Rocket i've edited my answer covering unavailability of `apache_request_headers` function. make a foreach in `$_SERVER`, put all keys starting with HTTP_ from `$_SERVER` to a new array.